# Display Value as Header for Group (XAML, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, grouping

I have got `ListView`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListUsers}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" >
 <ListView.View>
  <GridView>
   <GridViewColumn Header="Position" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Position}" />
   <GridViewColumn Header="Counter"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Counter}" /> 
 </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

I have made `ListView.GroupStyle`:

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
 <GroupStyle>
  <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
       <Expander IsExpanded="True">
        <Expander.Header>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Text="ReadTime" FontSize="14" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReadTime}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
          </StackPanel>
         </Expander.Header>
        <ItemsPresenter />
       </Expander>
      </ControlTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
   </Style>
  </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
 </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

Into my `ctor` in `ViewModel` I did like this:

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListUsers);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("ReadTime");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
```

How to now instead of `display text "ReadTime"` for each group, `display value` from ReadTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to now instead of display text "ReadTime" for each group, display value from ReadTime?

There is no *the* value since there is a header per group and a group may contain several values. If you want to display the *first* value in the group, you can use the `Items` collection of the group:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items[0].ReadTime}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

Comment: thank you @mm8, I have just implemented your solution and this is what I was looking for :)